# Magento indexer running via ssh but not cron job

Tags: php, magento, ssh, cron, indexer

I can reindex magento indexes via ssh command line with this code:

```
php -f [path to store]/shell/indexer.php reindex
```

or individual indexes with this code:

```
php -f [path to store]/shell/indexer.php -- reindex [index]
```

And that works fine. However whenever i try to reindex via cron i get this:

```
Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]

--status <indexer>            Show Indexer(s) Status
--mode <indexer>              Show Indexer(s) Index Mode
--mode-realtime <indexer>     Set index mode type "Update on Save"
--mode-manual <indexer>       Set index mode type "Manual Update"
--reindex <indexer>           Reindex Data
info                          Show allowed indexers
reindexall                    Reindex Data by all indexers
help                          This help

<indexer>     Comma separated indexer codes or value "all" for all indexers
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What is the cron task you have set, can you share?

Comment: I tried a few diffrant formats but its like this: php -f /home/[username]/public_html/shell/indexer.php -- reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the path to PHP. Try this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q [path to store]/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

This will depend on your path to PHP though!

Comment: Sulman your the man. Spend 2 days struggling with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide us the name of indexer

```
 php -f [path to store]/shell/indexer.php reindex **indexer_code**
```

**indexer_code** as mention below.
e.g.
//to reindex all indexes

```
php -f [path to store]/shell/indexer.php reindex all
```

Below are the list of indexer code

```
catalog_product_attribute     Product Attributes
catalog_product_price         Product Prices
catalog_url                   Catalog URL Rewrites
catalog_product_flat          Product Flat Data
catalog_category_flat         Category Flat Data
catalog_category_product      Category Products
catalogsearch_fulltext        Catalog Search Index
cataloginventory_stock        Stock Status
tag_summary                   Tag Aggregation Data
```

Comment: I have tried that but i get the same output as stated in my question. I have no idea why it is not working since it works fine in ssh

Comment: have you tried php -f [path to store]/shell/indexer.php reindex all

Comment: just go to magento root path and then change use this command php -f indexer.php reindex catalog_product_flat

Comment: I still get the same result

Answer (score 0):

The answer by sulman works, but only if you add it via  crontab -e command in ssh. No sure if this is due to permissions. In my case indexer.php had 755